# I'm pca with Deep neural network using TenserFlow with MNISt database, getting errors with shape of the data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to train the mnist database with the neural network after applying PCA. and I keep getting errors because of the data shape after applying the PCA. I'm not sure how to fit everything together. and how to go through the whole database, not just a small patch.

here is my code:

```
    <pre> <code>

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

datadir='/data' 
data= input_data.read_data_sets(datadir, one_hot=True)
train_x = data.train.images[:55000]
train_y= data.train.labels[:55000]
test_x = data.test.images[:10000]
test_y = data.test.labels[:10000]
print("original shape:   ", data.train.images.shape)

percent=600
pca=PCA(percent)
train_x=pca.fit_transform(train_x)
test_x=pca.fit_transform(test_x)
print("transformed shape:", data.train.images.shape)
train_x=pca.inverse_transform(train_x)
test_x=pca.inverse_transform(test_x)
c=pca.n_components_

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4));
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1);
image=np.reshape(data.train.images[3],[28,28])
plt.imshow(image, cmap='Greys_r')
plt.title("Original Data")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2);
image1=train_x[3].reshape(28,28)
image.shape
plt.imshow(image1, cmap='Greys_r')
plt.title("Original Data after 0.8 PCA")

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.plot(range(c), np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.grid()
plt.title("Cumulative Explained Variance")
plt.xlabel('number of components')
plt.ylabel('cumulative explained variance');


num_iters=10
hidden_1=1024
hidden_2=1024
input_l=percent
out_l=10
'''input layer'''
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28,28,1])
x=tf.reshape(x,[-1, input_l])

w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_l,hidden_1])) 
w2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_1,hidden_2]))
w3=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_2,out_l]))

b1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_1]))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_2]))
b3=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([out_l]))

Layer1=tf.nn.relu_layer(x,w1,b1)
Layer2=tf.nn.relu_layer(Layer1,w2,b2)
y_pred=tf.matmul(Layer2,w3)+b3
y_true=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,out_l])


loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y_pred, 
labels=y_true))
optimizer= tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.006).minimize(loss)
correct_pred=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
accuracy= tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

store_training=[]
store_step=[]
m = 10000

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(num_iters):
        indices = random.sample(range(0, m), 100)
        batch_xs = train_x[indices]
        batch_ys = train_y[indices]
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_true:batch_ys})
        training=sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:test_x, y_true:test_y})
        store_training.append(training)  
    testing=sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:test_x, y_true:test_y})

print('Accuracy :{:.4}%'.format(testing*100))
z_reg=len(store_training)
x_reg=np.arange(0,z_reg,1)
y_reg=store_training
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x_reg, y_reg,label='Regular Accuracy')
```

that is the error I got :

```
 
    "Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "<ipython-input-2-ff57ada92ef5>", line 135, in <module>
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_true:batch_ys})

 File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", 
 line 929, in run
  run_metadata_ptr)

 File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", 
 line 1128, in _run
 str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))

 ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor 'Reshape:0', 
 which has shape '(?, 600)'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I´d recommend to fit PCA only for train set since you may get different PCA components for train and test. So the easiest fix is to change the following piece of code:

```
percent=600
pca=PCA(percent)
train_x=pca.fit_transform(train_x)
test_x=pca.fit_transform(test_x)
```

to

```
percent=.80
pca=PCA(percent)
pca.fit(train_x)
train_x=pca.transform(train_x)
test_x=pca.transform(test_x)
```

Secondly, you use `percent=600` while doing PCA and then applying PCA inverse transform which means that you return to space with the original number of features. In order to start learning with the reduced number of PCA components you may also try to change this piece of code:

```
train_x=pca.inverse_transform(train_x)
test_x=pca.inverse_transform(test_x)
c=pca.n_components_
<plotting code>    
input_l=percent
```

to:

```
c=pca.n_components_
#plotting commented out   
input_l=c
```

It should give you the correct tensor dimensions for subsequent optimization procedure.

Comment: @micheal 

Thank you, your suggestions were really helpful.
my only problem now is how to plot the PCA data. as the shape doesn't fit. 

' image1=train_x[3].reshape(28,28)

  image.shape
  plt.imshow(image1, cmap='Greys_r')
  plt.title("Original Data after 0.8 PCA") '

Comment: To plot the image - make an inverse transform of train_x but then save its results to some other variable for plotting, e.g., like this in your code snippet: ipca_train_x=pca.inverse_transform(train_x)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2);
image1=ipca_train_x[3].reshape(28,28)

Comment: Thank you very much. everything is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your are reshaping your tensor `x` which has the shape `(None, 28 , 28, 1)` to shape `(None, percent)`
and you gave the value of `percent` as 600, and later you are giving the value of x as `(100, 28*28*1)` and feeding it to `x` which has the shape of `(None, 600)` and that doesn't match.